# Restore unsaved python script in qgis

Tags: pyqgis

Is there any way available to restore **my unsaved python script in qgis**? Yesterday I forget to save my scripts and now I open QGIS project I lost my all three scripts.

I used notepad++ or different IDEs that automatically save all your scripts but I guess this feature is not available in QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

It may be **possible** to restore unsaved scripts (**provided the temporary files are not deleted**) as mentioned by Nyall Dawson in the [ChangeLog for QGIS 2.14.2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/final-2_14_2/ChangeLog):

> [console] Allow running unsaved script files
>
> Previously a (non-default) option existed for auto-saving scripts on run, which would overwrite the existing script file if set, or save the script to a temporary file before running.
>
> Now, the auto-save option only applies to scripts which have already been saved an have a filename. **By default the console now can run scripts without filenames, or scripts with changes by transparently saving them out to a temporary file**.

I haven't tested this but my guess is the scripts are saved in your *TEMP* folder and depending on your system configuration, could still be there.

On Windows 10 you can open an Explorer Window and type in `%temp%`. Then search for the latest .py files.